# okta sign in widget for outside users

Tags: okta

We have OKTA and use it for employees within the organization.  What they want to do here is use the Okta sign in widget as a way of allowing outside users to access an app within our organization.  Is this possible to do with the sign in widget?  These users would have to be able to manage their own accounts.  We would not be doing the account management from this end so there would have to be a way to register new users from the widget.  Any help/examples of how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okta's Sign-In Widget doesn't currently support "self registration". To allow users to register themselves, you'd have to write some software on your end that would use the [Create User](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users.html#create-user) API call to do that.